# What does ^ after a type mean in c++?

Tags: syntax, c++-cli

I have some c++ code with function return types declared as `string^` or `IEnumerable<String^>^`, what does that mean?

edits: c#->c++/cli

Comment: It's not C# or C++, it's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in C#. You're looking at source code for C++/CLI, not C#.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI for a brief introduction.

The carat symbol basically means "this is a GC-tracked reference".

Comment: ah my bad, there were a few cpp files mixed with the cs files i was looking at :)

Comment: @Charles Ma: Note: C++/CLI is not C++ either.

Comment: Did you mean "C#", not "C++", in the answer?

Comment: @Tomalak: It (the question and tag) was changed.

Comment: Thanks Martin, yeah i just read up on C++/CLI, I'm new to windows development :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like managed C++, not C#. `^` means managed reference type.

Comment: [Managed C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B) the deprecated predecessor of [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. It is not valid there in C++. It's a "managed reference" type modifier for C++/CLI, a distinct language.