# What does the ^ do in a C# method call

Tags: c#, syntax, c++-cli

I cannot seen to find out the purpose of the `^` in a C# method call.

For example:

```
SomeObject::somemethod(ObjArg^ arg)
{
    // method body
}
```

What is the effect of the `^`?

Comment: This looks like C++/CLI, not c#

Comment: That is not valid c#. You can't do `SomeObject::`, or have a `^`

Comment: `I have been a [...] Java [...] programmer for over 20 years` - Welcome to the modern age. You might find C# language features such as LINQ, generics, delegates, and async/await really useful.

Comment: I think it could be a valid question if it was asked for c++/cli

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the caret (‘^’) mean in C++/CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing except for the multiple questions it duplicates.

Comment: @gunr2171 no, it is *not* a C# question, since that is *not* c# syntax.

Comment: @crashmstr, c# is stated twice, once in the title and once in the body, and the original tags included c#. If the OP made it as a mistake, you would have to radically edit the question to make it not about c#.

Comment: @crashmstr good point. Thought that as I posted the comment. Thanks for finding a duplicate

Comment: @gunr2171 The code sample is not C# and can not be C#, David Heffernan (286k) ALSO says it is not C#. So... not C# (and *no* edits to code need to make it about C++/CLI)

Comment: Also related: [What does ^ after a type mean in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599290/what-does-after-a-type-mean-in-c?rq=1), [What does the ^ character mean when used in C++ declarations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953002/what-does-the-character-mean-when-used-in-c-declarations?rq=1), [In C++/CLR, what does a hat character ^ do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500580/in-c-clr-what-does-a-hat-character-do?rq=1), and [What does the ^ do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835795/what-does-the-do?rq=1)

Answer (score 8):

This is not C#. This is C++/CLI. The `^` is the [Handle to Object Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx). It is used here to indicate that `arg` is a handle to a managed class of type `ObjArg`.

Comment: You got a badge for this +6 answer to a -6 question, didn't you?

Comment: @HighCore Nope, not yet. What badge would that be. I suppose they could give out a diabolo badge if you did that 6 times!

Comment: @DaavidHeffernan Ah, no. You're right. The badge I mean is [Reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal), but it requires a +20 answer to a -5 question.